# i'm made a rig with empties for controls but they are not appearing in one file

Tags: rendering

Every time I turn off the hair I can't see the mesh in Blender 2.8 but in rendered view it is visible and the rendered result is not showing it

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAkCIwWP-ciMCLOr-N-LBxoisppp8O4L/view?usp=sharing)

please try and render

Comment: could you be more precise please? What hair? What is visible and not visible? Perhaps show some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

In the [particle systems properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html), on the right side of the list of particle systems, there is a monitor and camera, these control the particle visibility in the viewport and render.

You have both visibility options turned off for your particle systems, you need to enable the monitor for viewport visibility and the camera for render visibility.

[image]